# download images in specific order

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a feature that displays a 360 degree view of a product. The view is represented by a sequence of stand alone images that are downloaded from the server.

From the point of view of the user experience, some images in the sequence are more important than the others. So when my code downloads images I would like to fetch the important ones first and display them immediately, and then fetch less important ones.

I know that I can order my images by their importance and download them sequentially, one after another, but I would like to take advantage of asynchronous downloading to reduce the bandwidth too.

Can anyone recommend anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the most important images in a first wave and then the other ones like this :

```
var firstImages = [];
var otherImages = [];

var count = firstImages.length;

var onloadfirstwave = function() {
   if (--count==0) {
      // lauches second wave
   }
};
// and for each image, do
firstImages[i].onload = onloadfirstwave;
firstImages[i].src = "someurl";
```

The second wave would be launched only after the first images are loaded and the parallelism of those first load would be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `setTimeout` and have a slightly increased delay (500ms) between each image.

Comment: do you mean start with the first image, wait a bit and proceed to the next one without waiting for the previous one to finish?

Comment: A timeout is no guarantee of setting image load order. You must hook into the onload event, then load the next image.

Comment: @Diodeus - By picking a reasonable value for the timeout you make it more likely, but, regardless, the earlier one should load faster than the later ones, since, if there are 10 pictures, the last one may start 5 seconds later than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The browser handles asynchronous loading for you, and is also what will limit the number of parallel downloads. Just preload the images the normal way. You don't need anything special.

Comment: yes. I am trying to make sure that my "important" images are downloaded first.

Comment: they will start downloading in the order you assign them. If the important images are bigger than the other ones, they may finish later, but you can just hide the less important images until then.

Answer (score 0):

The html can be created in js or html.
Html version:
    
      
      
      ...

```
var images = ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg',...],
    index = 0;
function load_next_image(){
  if(index<images.length){
    // if you want to create the img from js
    // this is the place to do so
    $('#img'+index).attr('src',images[index]).onload(load_next_image);
    index++;
  }else{
    // all images loaded
  }
}
load_next_image()
```