# Is it possible to dictate to a browser the order of the images it downloads ?

Tags: html, css, image, dom, browser

Ive got a fullscreen image slide with about 20 images each c. 250kb. That is quite allot to download and because i want each image to be seen in order Ive set the slider not to start until the first 4 images are downloaded. The only issue is that when run in a browser (chrome latest version) it seems to download all images at the same time meaning that the first 4 images finish loading about the same time as the other 20.

Is there a way i can tell the browser to download them in cronalogical order ie. if my html is like this :

`<div id="slider">
   <img src="one.jpg">
   <img src="two.jpg">
   <img src="three.jpg">
   <img src="four.jpg">
   <img src="five.jpg">
   <img src="six.jpg">
   ...
</div>`

Start on one.jpg wait until complete then start on two.jpeg etc ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [download images in specific order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194998/download-images-in-specific-order)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the img `onload` property in javascript.

```
var firstImage = new Image();
firstImage.src = 'some url';
firstImage.onload = function(){
 var secondImage = new Image();
 secondImage.src = 'some url';
 secondImage.onload = function(){
   //etc
 }
}
```

obviously doing those calls with a recursive function would be the actual implementation, but I wanted to make sure you saw the core concept.